# getting undefined error on useRef() in react-js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was working on webRtc based video conferencing app and getting video streams from browser

```
  const myVideo = useRef();
  const userVideo = useRef();
  const connectionRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
      .then((currentStream) => {
        setStream(currentStream);

        myVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Not able to get user media permisiion", err);
      })

    socket.on('me', (id) => setMe(id));

    socket.on('callUser', ({ from, name: callerName, signal }) => {
      setCall({ isReceivingCall: true, from, name: callerName, signal });
    });
  }, []);
```

I'm getting an error  `Not able to get user media permisiion TypeError: myVideo.current is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Ref.current is null because the ref is not set till after the function returns and the content is rendered. The `useEffect` hook fires every time the value of contents of the array passed to it changes. By passing observed in the array, the useEffect hook can be leveraged to accomplish your task.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
      .then((currentStream) => {
        setStream(currentStream);

        myVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Not able to get user media permisiion", err);
      })

    socket.on('me', (id) => setMe(id));

    socket.on('callUser', ({ from, name: callerName, signal }) => {
      setCall({ isReceivingCall: true, from, name: callerName, signal });
    });
  }, [myVideo]);
```

Comment: still getting the same error ```Not able to get user media permisiion TypeError: myVideo.current is undefined```

Comment: Try passing null to your useRef call or/and change myVideo in useEffect array to myVideo.current

Comment: my system is running but it is not giving stream to myVideo